# Doctrine executeQuery get final query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

When using Doctrine you're able to create a native query.

I'm running

```
$this->getEntityManager()
    ->getConnection()
    ->executeQuery($query, $parameter, $types)
    ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

The final query with all parameters is generated within `executeQuery()`. Is there a way to get to this final query created there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is no way to do this.

Doctrine sends the query as well as the parameters separately to the database and only the database puts them together. Therefore there is no way Doctrine could know about the full query.

A way to still debug the quere is to activate the general query log: [MySQL General query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html)

To activate it just create a new mysql config file like `/etc/mysql/conf.d/query_log.cnf` and put in the following content:

```
[mysqld]
log=/tmp/query.log # Path to your log file
```

In short: This will log all sql statements which in the end are executed in the mysql database.